# How to add detekt formatting with formatting rules in yml

Tags: android, detekt, ktlint

After upgrading detekt version to 1.23.1 from 1.21.0 I am getting following error.

Run failed with invalid config properties.
- Property 'formatting' is misspelled or does not exist.

I tried following https://github.com/detekt/detekt/discussions/5304
But unfortunately is fails and gives same error.

My project level build.gradle looks like this

```
tasks.withType(io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.Detekt).configureEach {
jvmTarget = Versions.java
setSource(files(projectDir))
exclude("**/legacymodule/**")
exclude("*/build/")
parallel = true
reports {
    xml.enabled = true
    html.enabled = false
    txt.enabled = false
}}
```

Does anybody knows how to correctly configure this? Help much appriciated.